# How to display typeahead in three different source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

In bootstrap tpeahead we using `uib-typeahead="lis for lis in product($viewValue)"`

i need to display three pars in type ahead below a,b array always dispaly type ahead

I have three different sources , display below source always

```
var a=['a','b','c'];
var b=['A','B','C'];
```

JS:

```
    $scope.product = function(val) {
            return $http.get('', {
                params : {
                    stk : val
                }
            }).then(
                    function(response) {
                        var a=['a','b','c'];
                        var b=['A','B','C'];
                        if (response.links) {
                            $("[uib-typeahead-popup].dropdown-menu").css('display','block');
                            return response.links
                                    .map(function(item) {
                                        return item.lis;
                                    });
                        };
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @KursadGulseven : display typeahead in three different source